# Spring security - Access http session on successful login handler

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to access the HttpSession after logging in, using the successful handler - `MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` - using `request.getSession(false)` , but it's null at this phase, any suggestions ?

Part of beans.xml:

```
 <security:http auto-config="false" 
                 entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"  />

    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />

    <security:remember-me />
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/login"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="com.me.filter.CustomAuthenticationFilter">

       <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/login"/>

       <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
       <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
       <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="com.me.web.filter.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login/success" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should define a session strategy to make the filter create the session on successful authentication, so beans.xml changes are like this:

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="com.me.filter.CustomAuthenticationFilter">

       <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/login"/>

       <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
       <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
       <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
       <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="registerSessionStrategy" />
</bean>

<bean id="registerSessionStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```